# Deploy Django to heroku with python 3.8

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to deploy my django app to Heroku.

but when I do

```
git push heroku master
```

I get the following error:

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Requested runtime (python-3.8) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to djangomessagesapi.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/djangomessagesapi.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/djangomessagesapi.git'
```

I've changed the python version in the runtime.txt file but is returns the same error.

**UPDATE**

I've managed to pass that with changing to python 3.6 in runtime.txt.
But when running I get a new error:

```
remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_07acbad0cae4c62609ee48dc9cec3685/requirements.txt (line 22)) (from versions: none)
remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_07acbad0cae4c62609ee48dc9cec3685/requirements.txt (line 22))
```

Comment: try removing `pkg-resources==0.0.0` from `requirements.txt`

Comment: @Hisham___Pak I did, it seems Heroku is reading the requirement from some tmp dir as seen in the error.